# エラーの意味がわかりません、どなたか解決方法を教えてください。

Tags: swift, swift4

ボタンの生成時にエラーが２つでました。

```
func makeButton(frame: CGRect, text: String, tag: Int) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
    button.frame = frame
    button.setTitle(text, for: UIControl.State.Normal) 
    //エラー文→【●’Normal' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set 】　       
    button.tag = tag
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick(_:)), 
    //エラー文→【 ●Use of unresolved identifier 'onClick'】
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return button
}
```

以上の様なエラーが出てしまいます。ザックリな質問ですみません。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift4では

`button.setTitle(text, for: UIControl.State.Normal)`
は
`button.setTitle(text, for: UIControl.State.normal)`
になります。

---

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick(_:)), 
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

は

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

となります。

---

`onClick`は自分で定義する必要があるので、

```
@objc func onClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // 自分で実装
}
```

を足すと `Use of unresolved identifier 'onClick'` のエラーが消えます。